# Why is HttpApplication._handlerFactories null?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, windbg, nullreferenceexception, system.web

I have 50+ asp.net 4.5 websites on 1 server(2012 R2), in 5 different App Pools. Occasionally I would met `NullReferenceException` when pool recycled and restarting with this stacktrace:

```
System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +16
System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +374
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +287
```

And this exception is gone if I modify web.config (adding/removing newlines in file end) for the website and send http request to it again.

I looked the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpApplication.cs#0a5d20033b06575b) for `HttpApplication.GetFactory(string type)`:

```
    private Hashtable _handlerFactories = new Hashtable();
    ....
    private IHttpHandlerFactory GetFactory(string type) {
        HandlerFactoryCache entry = (HandlerFactoryCache)_handlerFactories[type];
        if (entry == null) {
            entry = new HandlerFactoryCache(type);
            _handlerFactories[type] = entry;
        }

        return entry.Factory;
    }
```

and the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpApplication.cs#15b47b03dbf19311) for `HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.IExecutionStep.Execute()`:

```
            ...
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(configType)) {
                IHttpHandlerFactory factory = _application.GetFactory(configType);
            string pathTranslated = request.PhysicalPathInternal;
             ...
```

I can't find anywhere a `NullReferenceException` could be thrown. So I use windbg with sos to debug, here is some useful information I get:

```
0:061> !eeversion
4.0.30319.34011 free
Server mode with 8 gc heaps
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.34011 retail build

0:061> !clrstack -a
OS Thread Id: 0x208c (61)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
0000006c11cdd590 00007ff97bb6d841 System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(System.String)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>
        type = <no data>
    LOCALS:
        <no data>

0000006c11cdd5d0 00007ff97bb93067 System.Web.HttpApplication+MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    PARAMETERS:
        this (0x0000006c11cdd690) = 0x0000006b4448d188
    LOCALS:
        0x0000006c11cdd630 = 0x00000067c515b380
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        <no data>
        0x0000006c11cdd618 = 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000006c11cdd610 = 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000006c11cdd608 = 0x0000000000000000
        <no data>

0000006c11cdd690 00007ff97bb6bf60 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)
    PARAMETERS:
        this (0x0000006c11cdd730) = 0x0000006b44489978
        step = <no data>
        completedSynchronously (0x0000006c11cdd740) = 0x0000006c11cdd822
    LOCALS:
        0x0000006c11cdd708 = 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000006c11cdd700 = 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000006c11cdd6f8 = 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000006c11cdd6f0 = 0x0000000000000000
        <no data>
......

0:061> r edx
edx=c5186090

0:061> !dumpobj edx
Name:        System.String
MethodTable: 00007ff97e83fc48
EEClass:     00007ff97e1d1aa8
Size:        110(0x6e) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
String:      System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler

0:061> !dumpobj 0000006b44489978
Name:        ASP.global_asax
MethodTable: 00007ff92b6c2218
EEClass:     00007ff92b65ea50
Size:        224(0xe0) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\347f4708\a88050db\App_global.asax.v9t8txcb.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007ff97bcf6348  4000fa5        8 ...pApplicationState  0 instance 0000006ac4269f28 _state
00007ff97bcf4a98  4000fa6       10 ...m.Web.HttpContext  0 instance 0000000000000000 _initContext
00007ff97bcf6fa8  4000fa7       18 ...b.HttpAsyncResult  0 instance 0000000000000000 _ar
00007ff97bcf6f38  4000fa9       20 ...pModuleCollection  0 instance 0000006b44489a58 _moduleCollection
00007ff97d67b558  4000fc5       28 ....EventHandlerList  0 instance 0000006b4448a578 _events
00007ff97bcfea28  4000fc6       30 ...ventHandlersTable  0 instance 0000006b4448ab20 _asyncEvents
00007ff97bd03070  4000fc7       38 ...ation+StepManager  0 instance 0000006b4448d160 _stepManager
00007ff97e84ba78  4000fc8       40 ...ding.WaitCallback  0 instance 0000006b4448d120 _resumeStepsWaitCallback
00007ff97e84f2e8  4000fc9       48     System.EventArgs  0 instance 00000067c44c5fd8 _appEvent
00007ff97e843c08  4000fca       50 ...ections.Hashtable  0 instance 0000000000000000 _handlerFactories
00007ff97e8562d0  4000fcb       58 ...ections.ArrayList  0 instance 0000000000000000 _handlerRecycleList
00007ff97e83e3e0  4000fcc       d0       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _hideRequestResponse
00007ff97bcf4a98  4000fcd       60 ...m.Web.HttpContext  0 instance 00000067c515b380 _context
00007ff97e83fe78  4000fce       68     System.Exception  0 instance 0000000000000000 _lastError
00007ff97e83e3e0  4000fcf       d1       System.Boolean  1 instance                1 _timeoutManagerInitialized
00007ff97bcf6e70  4000fd0       70 ....HttpSessionState  0 instance 0000000000000000 _session
00007ff97e844248  4000fd1       78 ...ation.CultureInfo  0 instance 0000000000000000 _appLevelCulture
00007ff97e844248  4000fd2       80 ...ation.CultureInfo  0 instance 0000000000000000 _appLevelUICulture
00007ff97e844248  4000fd3       88 ...ation.CultureInfo  0 instance 0000000000000000 _savedAppLevelCulture
00007ff97e844248  4000fd4       90 ...ation.CultureInfo  0 instance 0000000000000000 _savedAppLevelUICulture
00007ff97e83e3e0  4000fd5       d2       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _appLevelAutoCulture
00007ff97e83e3e0  4000fd6       d3       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _appLevelAutoUICulture
00007ff97b8c2930  4000fd7       98 ...ion, System.Web]]  0 instance 0000006b4448cc28 _pipelineEventMasks
00007ff97d68a598  4000fd8       a0 ...ponentModel.ISite  0 instance 0000000000000000 _site
00007ff97e83e3e0  4000fdb       d4       System.Boolean  1 instance                1 _initInternalCompleted
00007ff97bcf7040  4000fdc       c8         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _appRequestNotifications
00007ff97bcf7040  4000fdd       cc         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _appPostNotifications
00007ff97e83fc48  4000fde       a8        System.String  0 instance 00000068c3697978 _currentModuleCollectionKey
00007ff97e8402c0  4000fe0       b0      System.Object[]  0 instance 0000006b4448a5c0 _moduleContainers
00007ff97e845740  4000fe1       b8        System.Byte[]  0 instance 0000000000000000 _entityBuffer
```

As we can see, `HttpApplication._handlerFactories` is null (0000000000000000), I don't understand why this is happening, because from the source code, this field is initialized before constructor calling, and I can find none write operation to it besides this.

So my question is, why is it null?

I have the dump file in case any more information is required.

Comment: Is your code multithreaded? If so, another thread may have set _handlerFactories to null just prior to current thread calling GetFactory(). Dump all managed thread stacks with `~*e !clrstack` and you might see this case.

Comment: @MarcSherman I tried, only 3 threads are CLR threads, I don't see anything useful. I think my code hasn't had the chance to execute yet when the exception was thrown because my global exception handler set up at application start didn't log it. All the websites are running the same code, so in App Pool's view, it might be multi-threaded. However, every website should be in their own AppDomain, they shouldn't affect each other.

Comment: Is there any Singleton pattern, static methods or static constructors in code near this issue? Static stuff might run before the object is fully created.

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes there are, it's the first asp.net request which initializes the whole application. I'll try to create a minimal reproduce.